# Unable to format my Data field using Data Annotation

Tags: c#, asp.net, asp.net-mvc, data-annotations

i am working on an asp.net mvc web application , and i have added the following data annotation into my model class :-

```
[Display(Name = "Start Date")]
[DisplayFormat(ApplyFormatInEditMode = true,
DataFormatString = "{0:dd MMMM yyyy hh:mm:ss tt}")]
public Nullable<System.DateTime> StartDate { get; set; }
```

Then i use the following to render the view which contains the date field :-

```
@Html.Action("LatestAssets","Home")
```

The action method looks as follow:-

```
[HttpGet]
public PartialViewResult LatestAssets()
{
    var tech = repository.LatestTechnology().OrderByDescending(a => a.TechnologyID).Take(10).ToList() ;
    return PartialView("_Latest",tech);


}
```

But the data was displayed as `12/4/2013 10:17:54 AM` instead of `04 December 2013 10:17:54 AM`, so can anyone adivce , and is the problem related to the face that i am rendering a partial view ?

Comment: john use 'MM' instead of using MMMM

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In your view check how the StartDate being called. Use DisplayFor instead. (works for me)

```
@Html.DisplayFor(m => m.StartDate)
```

I don't think this is related to partial views.